# phantomjs/highchart: how to handle legend overflow when exported to PNG/PDF

Tags: highcharts, phantomjs

My result is:
[image]

Any suggestion welcomed. Still stuck in this issue. 
Sometimes, there are too many items in the legend, how to handle legend overflow. One way is to set the height and width according to the size of the series (exporting setting in the following). **Any better way?**

```
{
  "subtitle": {
    "text": "2016-05-19 12:09 to 2016-05-26 12:09"
  },
  "title": {
    "text": "Query"
  },
  "series": [

  ],
  "yAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": "Count"
    }
  },
  "tooltip": {
    "pointFormat": "<span style=\\\\"color:{point.color}\\\\">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>"
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "column": {
      "colorByPoint": false
    }
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "labels": {
      "style": {
        "fontSize": "9px"
      }
    },
    "type": "category"
  },
  "exporting": {
    "sourceHeight": 3000,
    "chartOptions": {
      "chart": {
        "height": 2000
      },
      "legend": {
        "maxHeight": 1600
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "chart",
  "legend": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set undefined value for the maxHeight parameter in the exporting object.

```
legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        maxHeight: 40
    },
    exporting:{
        chartOptions:{
        legend:{
            maxHeight: undefined
        }
      }
    },
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/7kLyartr/

Comment: I tried modifying my code above to use undefined as maxHeight (maxHeight = undefined,). but failed.

Comment: Can you update my code with yours to introduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to override the function that you are referring to with a simple function that will just return same value as its first argument. However, disabling a legend navigation like that will make your legend rather big - depending on actual data.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zwL7v6by/

```
$(function() {
  Highcharts.Legend.prototype.handleOverflow = function(legendHeight) {
    return legendHeight;
  };

  $('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      showInLegend: true,
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    }]
  });
});
```